# how to tell if an association changed in a rails edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, relationship

I'm using `simple_form_for` to create/update two models that are related by using `f.association`. But whenever I update it, I need to somehow get a collection of what changed in the association. It is a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between a model called ProjectLevels and a model called PackageContents. So in the `project_levels_controller` in the strong params I have `package_content_ids: []`. But if I try to use `@project_level.package_content_ids_changed?` it gives an undefined method error, even though `@project_level.name_changed?` will work. I also tried `@project_level.package_contents.changed?`and it also gives a no method error. So how can I see which package_contents were added or deleted from a project_level in an edit form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare array from params in your controller:

```
new_ids = params[:package_content_ids]
```

with current model's ids (*before* you assign params to it):

```
old_ids = @project_level.package_contents_ids
```

You can just use standard Ruby array methods to gain information you need:

```
old_ids - new_ids # what was deleted
new_ids - old_ids # what was added
new_ids & old_ids # what was not changed
new_ids.sort == old_ids.sort # if something was changed
```

Comment: Don't know how I didn't catch this... Thank you!